# Google Apps Script Undo function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, undo, google-sheets-formula

I am setting up a spreadsheet and I need to protect cells on copy. As Google Sheets doesn't copy protection when a new sheet is copied, I came across this code. It is an undo function but it only works with text and not formula. Any ideas on how to change it?

I have changeed `.getValue` to `.getFormula` but with no luck.

```
var masterSheetName = "Master" // sheet where the cells are protected from updates
  var helperSheetName = "Backup" // sheet where the values are copied for later checking

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var masterSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  if (masterSheet.getName() != masterSheetName) return;

  var masterRange = masterSheet.getActiveRange();

  var helperSheet = ss.getSheetByName(helperSheetName);
  var helperRange = helperSheet.getRange(masterRange.getA1Notation());
  var newValue = masterRange.getValues();
  var oldValue = helperRange.getValues();
  Logger.log("newValue " + newValue);
  Logger.log("oldValue " + oldValue);
      Logger.log(typeof(oldValue));
  if (oldValue == "" || isEmptyArrays(oldValue)) {
    helperRange.setValues(newValue);
  } else {
    Logger.log(oldValue);
    masterRange.setValues(oldValue);

  }
}
```

Comment: .`.getValues()` returns the values a cell displays, which would be the result of the formula.  [`.getFormulas()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getFormulas()) will return the formula if one exists, an empty string if there is no formula. See the linked GAS reference.  There is also an associated [.setFormulas()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setFormulas(String)) for placing new formulas.

Comment: @Karl_S Hi, i've been trying this but with no luck. When i edit a cell with text, i expect it to change back to the formula, not stay as text.

Comment: @Karl_S Figured it out, line 10 should be .getFormulas and the others .setFormulas

Comment: Actually you should probably have created a line like you now have fro line 10 and then tested to see if anything returns a blank string, at which point you would get the values as well.  Or just get the formulas and the values.  But if you can 100% guarantee that you only have formulas, then you are probably good to go.